Load model in typescript
I've attached screenshots of the error, the relevant part of my code, and the FBX file properties:

error
code
description
fsfs 1. What causes the "Cannot find the version number" error when loading an FBX file in THREE.js? 2. How can I fix this issue to successfully load my FBX file? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

